# Unable to install Eclipse plugin - ADT

Tags: android, eclipse

I am currently running a 32bit vista and installed the latest version of the sdk from developer.android.com.
The problem is that when I try to install the plugin it gives me this error message:

```
Unable to read repository at https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/content.xml.
Unable to read repository at https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/content.xml.
Permission denied: connect
```

This happens for every link, even if you type in something like google.com. I tried doing http instead of https but to no avail.

If you need more information just say so below in the comments. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

I got it. I just needed to disable the firewall. That's it.